# How to calculate the surface area of a mesh

Tags: unity, c#, mathematics, geometry, computational-geometry

I am looking for a way to **calculate surface area of a 3D mesh object** and [found this code from a Unity forum](https://forum.unity.com/threads/figuring-out-the-volume-and-surface-area.117388/):

```
 public float Area(Mesh m)
 {
     Vector3[] mVertices = m.vertices;
     Vector3 result = Vector3.zero;
     for (int p = mVertices.Length - 1, q = 0; q < mVertices.Length; p = q++)
     {
         result += Vector3.Cross(mVertices[q], mVertices[p]);
     }
     Debug.Log(result);
     result *= 0.5f;
     return result.magnitude;
 }
```

But the problem is that it is not providing the correct area as I have found from testing the fbx with Revit. Revit is showing a different surface area from what this code shows.

Here is a sample mesh

**Front**

[image]

**Back**
[image]

**Top**
[image]

Its surface area as calculated by the function above is 97.4913,
while in Revit it's actually 52.811 \$m^2\$.

I don't know how revit calculate it but it provide area and volume information automatically (i have no idea how even revit works).
[image]

Comment: This is off by almost factor 2. Maybe you have double-sided polygons in that mesh which Unity counts twice but Revit only counts as one?

Comment: good point @Philipp! but i have other object as well and difference is not remaing the same. This should be work equally with all meshes. sometime it near the result which i am calculating and sometime its thrice of the revit calculation.

Comment: Like one of another mesh it is 23.8991 in unity while 23.612 meter square in revit. another object is 5.17 while in revit its area calculation is 15.318 meter square.

Comment: Now that you've shown us what you're doing in Revit: yes, you're computing the surface area of A FACE or A PROJECTION of the mesh (ie. "how much wallpaper do we need to cover one side?") Not the whole surface area of the mesh ("how much wallpaper do we need to cover the whole thing?") Which value do you want in the end? What are you using this surface area calculation for?

Comment: For the moment i just want to show the same as revit showing.

Comment: I think it is considering the complete mesh (only the selected mesh from back and front not the whole building)

Comment: @MuhammadFaizanKhan If you really just want to know how Revit calculates surface area, then we can not help you. Revit is closed source, so only the developers at Autodesk know how it works. But if you would provide us with an actual problem related to your game, then we might be able to help you.

Comment: @Philipp area is not a secret thing. i have already calcuated the volume and it is perfect according to the revit, you can see it here. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53430856/calculating-width-height-and-volume-of-atypical-object only area has a problem.

Comment: @MuhammadFaizanKhan Have you actually done the math and calculated by hand whether Unity or Revit gives you the "correct" surface area? (whatever "correct" means for your particular purpose, which you still haven't told us). Personally I would try this first with a very simple object, like a 1 unit cube, and then try gradually more complex geomoetries until I found the cases which one of these two programs interprets differently than I would.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Looking at the formula you're using, it looks like it's designed to calculate the area of a planar polygon, where the vertices are all in clockwise / counterclockwise order about the perimeter.

That's not the same as a 3D mesh.

Try something like this instead:

- we'll iterate over the triangles of the mesh
- for each triangle, we'll compute vectors representing the two edges
- half the magnitude of the cross product of these edges gives us the area of the triangle
- we'll sum these triangle areas to accumulate the full surface area

Note that if your mesh has any double-sided faces or internal faces, they can bias this result.

```
float CalculateSurfaceArea(Mesh mesh) {
    var triangles = mesh.triangles;
    var vertices = mesh.vertices;

    double sum = 0.0;

    for(int i = 0; i < triangles.Length; i += 3) {
        Vector3 corner = vertices[triangles[i]];
        Vector3 a = vertices[triangles[i + 1]] - corner;
        Vector3 b = vertices[triangles[i + 2]] - corner;

        sum += Vector3.Cross(a, b).magnitude;
    }

    return (float)(sum/2.0);
}
```

Since it now looks like you want to compute just the area of the mesh facing in a particular direction, you can try this version instead. Pass the direction you want to view the mesh from and it should compute the projected surface area of the faces facing at least partially in that direction.

```
float CalculateFacingArea(Mesh mesh, Vector3 direction) {
    direction = direction.normalized;
    var triangles = mesh.triangles;
    var vertices = mesh.vertices;

    double sum = 0.0;

    for(int i = 0; i < triangles.Length; i += 3) {
        Vector3 corner = vertices[triangles[i]];
        Vector3 a = vertices[triangles[i + 1]] - corner;
        Vector3 b = vertices[triangles[i + 2]] - corner;

        float projection = Vector3.Dot(Vector3.Cross(b, a), direction);
        if (projection > 0f)
            sum += projection;
    }

    return (float)(sum/2.0);
}
```

Comment: The object is full model from both side as the picture depicted in the question. I have applied your method but result are not same according to the revit tool calculation. I don't know how revit calculating the area

Comment: Could it be giving you the area of a section of the mesh (eg. like the square footage of a floorplan, rather than the total amount of surface including the walls and ceiling)? Why don't you edit your question to show us how you're computing your surface area in Revit, so we can investigate that angle.

Comment: I have no problem to share with you but l really don't know how revit calculate it. please see the updated question i have updated

Comment: Since it looks like you're trying to compute the area of a projection of the mesh, you can try the new version I've added instead. This filters out back faces and only sums up the projections of the surface area of forward-facing polygons in your chosen plane.

Comment: I have tested your code and its working fine but the problem is that each object has different front facing axis, i mean different x y z directions so for each object i have to provide different facing direction.

Comment: That doesn't sound like a problem that we have enough information to help you with. You haven't answered any of our questions about how you're using this number in your game, or what game feature it's supporting, and we've only seen one of your objects. So we don't have any leads we could use to help you select the right facing direction for each object for your game's needs — we know neither the objects nor the needs. Try sharing details about this feature in a new question and we can try to shed some light there.

Comment: Don't get angry @DMGregory! I know that you are curious to know what i am doing but believe me i don't know what the client going to do with the value of a surface area of an object. My task is only to display the width, height, breath, volume and area of a selected object. Currently, I am selecting an object on mouseDown event and passing the selected object's width, height, volume n area to a UI label element. The more thing I can provide you that it is a project related to architecture and building.

Comment: I am able to get an object width, height breath and volume but unable to find the area, therefore i have asked this question here. You can check this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53430856/calculating-width-height-and-volume-of-atypical-object where i am getting width, height and volume

Comment: I am poor in math or geometry subjects and still learning how your code is actually working. Thanks for the help

Comment: I'm not angry, just pointing out that when you don't answer our questions, we're limited in how we can help you. Just your comment above already contains far more information that you could have put in your question from the start. So next time, do that. If your client has asked you for the surface area of the mesh, they probably want the first example there. If you use the second version, it sounds like you should let the user click to select the projection plane. I can explain anything you like about the math, but it's really just summing triangle areas as described in the answer.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion but I try to write concise question so that community members easily get it and answer it. Additionally, I was think, i have shared the enough information. Anyway, next time i will try my best to explain.

Comment: Yeah, it seems that you have adding the triangles but understanding that why did u subtracting each 2nd and 3rd vertex with the corner vertex and then getting cross product of both vector and  dot product, then sum and divsion with 2.0. blah blah...

Comment: Anyway the answer is helpful; by providing specific direction it is giving me the area as revit tool is showing. Next thing that i have to identified how can i provide the right direction information to the above function on click. Means how to know projection plane on click

Comment: "Subtracting each 2nd & 3rd vertex" just gives the two edges of the triangle radiating from the initial corner. The cross product divided by two gives the area of the triangle (same as in the code you were using). The dot product is what handles projecting this area onto the plane of interest. "How to know projection plane on click" sounds like doing a raycast and taking hit.normal, no?

Comment: "hit.normal", Yeah i tried but it is not trustworthy as it is not providing correct result for every mesh. Maybe my objects are not correctly model?

Comment: Sounds like something you should post as a new question, with a complete description of what you're trying to do, how you're doing it, and how the results are differing from what you intend/expect

Comment: Yes, you are right. I will do that after some experiments. Thanks!!! you are always helpful.

Answer (score 1):

Shamelessly building on [DMGregorys answer](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/a/165647/73859)..

You can also define this as an [extension method](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/extension-methods) for the `Mesh` class.

```
// Put this in some static Util class
public static float CalculateSurfaceArea(this Mesh mesh) {
    var triangles = mesh.triangles;
    var vertices = mesh.vertices;

    double sum = 0.0;

    for (int i = 0; i < triangles.Length; i += 3) {
        Vector3 corner = vertices[triangles[i]];
        Vector3 a = vertices[triangles[i + 1]] - corner;
        Vector3 b = vertices[triangles[i + 2]] - corner;

        sum += Vector3.Cross(a, b).magnitude;
    }

    return (float)(sum / 2.0);
}
```

you can now simply call

```
Mesh mesh = Surface.GetComponent<MeshFilter>().sharedMesh;
float area = mesh.CalculateSurfaceArea();
```